# How to display two tables side by side

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of difficulty. How do I display two tables side by side? More specifically I need to display one table with two columns, miles and kilometers. The miles will count up by one while the equal number of kilometers are displayed (one mile is 1.609 kilometers). The table would stop at 10 miles. It would look something like this:

```
mile         kilometers

1            1.609

2            3.218

...

10           16.090
```

The second table would start with 20 kilometers and go up by multiple of 5's to 65. It would look something like this:

```
kilometer    miles

20           12.430

25           15.538

...

65           40.398
```

Comment: is it gonna be printed in console or where?

Comment: are you using a graphical user interface like Swing? Which? How do you display your tables now?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want two `JTable` added to a `JPanel` that has its layout set as a `GridLayout(1, 2)`. Make sure to wrap the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` so you see the header row.

```
JTable table1 = // Define your JTable
JTable table2 = // Define your JTable

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table1));
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table2));
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error saying that I need an = after .add and .setLayout

Comment: Did you replace the comments that say "Define your JTable" with actually defining your JTable?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic structure:

```
<Table>
    <tr>
        <td><table id=1><tr><td>What ever you need here for column 1</td><td>and for column 2</td></tr><table></td>
        <td><table id=2><tr><td>Content of the second tabel gos here</td><td>and for column 2</td></tr><table></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

You can do similar things with DIV which is more common now...

Comment: hey, structure of how to form table have no difference for Java or C# or VBScript. Rules of HTML applies to all. How you convert that structure in your area that is another story. On  top of that I see lot of tags saying that it for Oracle when in reality it was simple t-SQL question.